# Run shell script from Apache conf or at Apache (re)start

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, centos

I have a complex web application that contains a lot of dynamic Aliases. I created a shellscript that updates the .conf file(s) with these aliases. Is it possible to call this shellscript from within the Apache conf? So something like:

```
RunScript /etc/myapp/updateconf.sh
Include /etc/myapp/*.conf
```

Or alternatively, is there a good way to add this script as a hook to the /etc/init.d/apache2 or /etc/init.d/httpd script? I am looking for a solution that works on both CentOS and Ubuntu. If I am totally approaching this the wrong way, any other suggestions are welcome as well.

Comment: How often does your configuration get updated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can call it before starting the Apache in init script, something like this:

```
start() {
        echo -n $"Starting $prog: "
        check13 || exit 1
        . /etc/myapp/updateconf.sh
        LANG=$HTTPD_LANG daemon --pidfile=${pidfile} $httpd $OPTIONS
        RETVAL=$?
        echo
        [ $RETVAL = 0 ] && touch ${lockfile}
        return $RETVAL
}
```

Comment: Actually I ended up creating an additional init script which first runs the shell script and then calls the apache2 init script.

Answer (score 1):

If the configuration needs to be updated regularly, I would be tempted to do this via a cron job and use the `graceful` option to when restarting apache. If you want to do this hourly/daily/weekly/monthly then you could put a script in the relevant /etc/cron.* directory and it will be run for you.

```
#!/bin/bash

/etc/myapp/updateconf.sh && /sbin/service httpd graceful 
                            # change to /usr/sbin/service apache2 graceful 
                            # for ubuntu
```

would work.

If you need to do this when your system starts then edit `/etc/crontab` and add an `@reboot` entry

```
@reboot   root    /etc/myapp/updateconf.sh && /sbin/service httpd graceful
```

If apache hasn't already started it won't be started by the graceful option but your config files will be updated ready for apache to start. If apache is running it will be restarted.